# Page go and back using finger gesture (like Safari) in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

iOS Safari app allows you to page go and back using finger gesture, but it also enables you to "stop" the state of the view during swiping if you hold your fingers at that position. Let me explain this a bit more clearly using the following illustration:

Here's the view:

```
[    ]
```

In the above view, when I swipe from the right edge of the view, I want to make another view stacked on top of the current view or show the "hidden" view beneath the current view, such as the following:

```
[   []
```

And if I continue to the swiping, the state is continuously changing, like:

```
[  [ ]
```

And

```
[ [  ]
```

And finally, the new view stops there, meaning the old view still accounts for a quarter of the entire screen. And when I swipe after the new view ends its transition, or even during the transition, to the right direction, I want to cover the new view again. I think this behavior can be implemented using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` class, but don't know how to write it in the method.

Suppose I already put swipe or pan gesture recognizer (which is the appropriate by the way?) with right gesture being enabled on the first or "uncovered" view and put some objects in the second or "covered" view and want those hidden objects to be shown to the user with response to the swiping or panning of an user, and hence I wrote the following method called `handlePanGesture:`

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
```

}

can anyone help me fill code in the method?

And also, I found `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` class was added to iOS SDK in iOS7. Which method should I use to implement the above behavior?

I'm on Xcode 5 and iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks 10.9.1.

Comment: It's a built-in feature if you use `UINavigationController`

Comment: I don't use navigation controller, just want to pile a view on top of another view in storyboard, and show the hidden view with response to an user's finger gesture.

Comment: what you are trying to do is very complex, best thing you can do is use the navigation controller as it is built-in. If you want to try to do it yourself, look at my answer on this thread, it might help you, but it still need a LOT of work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557357/ios-7-safari-like-history-dragging-gesture-using-uiwebview/20347174#20347174

Comment: jcesar, thanks. Looks like what I should use is either navigation controller or third-party libraries to focus on the exact work. As to your linked question, yeah, I found it before opening this thread, but it still didn't fit my needs here. Thanks for your suggestion though.